# how can i sync downloaded mp3 from document directory to user's music library in ios?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I  downloaded the mp3 in document directory. But i am not able to sync this mp3 to music library in iPhone. Please can anyone help me ? I have searched on stack overflow but i didn't get any answere.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible...otherwise all those "free mp3" apps would have this feature